# Кнопки Вперед/назад Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html5-history-api

Использую *Ajax* для подгрузки страниц, и *history api*, чтобы работали кнопки вперед и назад. 
Вот скрипт, который отвечает за вперед/назад:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
var returnLocation = history.location || document.location;
var backUri = returnLocation.toString();
$.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url: backUri,
                    success: function(mes){
                        $('#content').html(mes);
                        reinitOpacity();
                        $(window).scroll();

                    }
                });
    });
```

Есть плагин галереи *prettyPhoto*, и при просмотре каждого изображения этот скрипт срабатывает, что в последствии приводит к неправильной работе плагина.

Существует ли какой-нибудь другой способ обрабатывать кнопки вперед/назад в браузере?